# Barplots and adding extra labels in R

Tags: r

Here is part of my data

```html
Variable    Low Medium  High
D1  0   37.68116    62.31884
D2  0   55.07246    44.92754
D3  1.449275    47.82609    50.72464
D4  0   33.33333    66.66667
D5  1.449275    39.13043    59.42029
D6  2.898551    46.37681    50.72464
D7  0   42.02899    57.97101
D8  2.898551    49.27536    47.82609
D9  xx  xx  xx
D10 xx  xx  xx
D11 xx  xx  xx
D12 xx  xx  xx
D13 xx  xx  xx
D14 xx  xx  xx
D15 xx  xx  xx
D16 xx  xx  xx
D17 xx  xx  xx
D18 xx  xx  xx
D19 xx  xx  xx
D20 xx  xx  xx
D21 xx  xx  xx
D22 xx  xx  xx
D23 xx  xx  xx
D24 xx  xx  xx
```

I want to get the following barplot. But I want to add labels to this plot. For example, D1, D2 and D3 get a label of **Time1, St1** and D4, D5 and D6 a label of **Time1, St2** and so on. Can we do it in R?

Here is the plot of interest:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~Variable, ~Low, ~Medium,  ~High,
  "D1", 0, 37.68116, 62.31884,
  "D2", 0, 55.07246, 44.92754,
  "D3", 1.449275, 47.82609, 50.72464,
  "D4", 0, 33.33333, 66.66667,
  "D5", 1.449275, 39.13043, 59.42029,
  "D6", 2.898551, 46.37681, 50.72464,
  "D999", 2.898551, 46.37681, 50.72464
)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels = c("Low", "Medium", "High")),
         label =
           case_when(
             Variable %in% c("D1", "D2", "D3") ~ "Time1St1",
             Variable %in% c("D4", "D5", "D6") ~ "Time1St2",
             T ~ "none_from_specified"
           ),
         label = factor(label, c("Time1St1", "Time1St2", "none_from_specified")) # here you specify the ordering
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Variable, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
  facet_wrap(~label, scales = "free", strip.position = "bottom") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "orange", "grey"), aesthetics = "fill")
```

Comment: Thanks, would it be possible for you to run it to 24 Variablesas I get an error

Comment: Sure, but you need to specify them in the code here so that it is clear what label is to be used:
Variable %in% c("D1", "D2", "D3") ~ "Time1St1",
Variable %in% c("D4", "D5", "D6") ~ "Time1St2"

Comment: I got it, thank you very much, How I can I ordered it For example Time1St1, Time1St2, Time2St1 and Time2St2...

Comment: There are multiple ways to fo that. Please ask a new question for that.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the information on how to do custom ordering of the labels.